# Trying to update to Android SDK 2.3 on Eclipse causes adb loss

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt, android-sdk-2.3

Today, i tried to update the Android tools i use on Eclipse to version 8.0 and the Android SDK to version 2.3. This caused a loss of adb from tools directory. I managed to retrieve it again and put it back. Then, i searched the forum and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375175/could-not-find-adb-exe-after-upgrade-to-android-sdk-2-3), that eventually helped me to solved it, by updating the Eclipse first.

So, why is there no warning of proceeding to Android tools update, without updating the Eclipse first, can cause this kind of troubles?

It could have saved some time...

Comment: All information required to update is on the developer site at http://d.android.com I voted to close this question as it is not a real question.

Comment: I also had this problem, I reinstalled the Android SDK 2.3 and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to offend anyone, I concur with Niko.

If it was mentioned that Eclipse ADT plugin MUST be updated as adb has been moved - it would have saved some pain.

I have installed these things since Mr Android was born, and I had trouble myself. I go to forums to seek solutions, when I have read the docs and they did not help, and probably whine a bit, coz I'm sure more people are facing this issue. :)

I have a step by step process here:
http://codevelle.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/up-and-running-with-sdk-2-3-with-eclipse/

Thanks,
Shesh

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the docs. The /tools folder has been moved to /platform-tools. You need to add this new location to your (class)path ...

Regards
Harald