# Android: I have problem with SDK after upgrade of that

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, upgrade, android-sdk-2.3

today I upgrade my SDK 2.2 to 2.3. every thing was OK with 2.2 but after upgrading to 2.3 adb.exe couldn't find by the android.

What should I do?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find adb.exe - after upgrade to Android SDK 2.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375175/could-not-find-adb-exe-after-upgrade-to-android-sdk-2-3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find adb.exe - after upgrade to Android SDK 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375175/could-not-find-adb-exe-after-upgrade-to-android-sdk-2-3)