# <PATH> was unexpected at this time. Android compilation failure after SDK update

Tags: android, sdk

I am on Vista and After updating the Android SDK through `'Android.bat update sdk'` I get this compilation failure.

```
<PATH> was unexpected at this time.
```

Seems like a problem with Windows path with 'spaces'. Will try removing spaces from the path.

**Helpful links**

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12740

[Could not find adb.exe - after upgrade to Android SDK 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375175/could-not-find-adb-exe-after-upgrade-to-android-sdk-2-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is your question? You've identified the problem (spaces in the path), so the solution should be pretty simple as well. (Rename the folder the SDK files are in to one without spaces.)

Comment: will mark this as the answer, once I verify. Battery died while moving SDK to a new location. Not sure what else is broken.